# How can I pass an argument to a batch in shortcut if calling a vbs script prior

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm using windows and creating a shortcut to call the following.

```
\\myserver\myfolder\inv.vbs \\myserver\myfolder\mybat.bat
```

I have created the VBS script to not show the batch window (run hidden).

```
inv.vbs = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

I want to pass a parameter to the batch, something like:

```
\\myserver\myfolder\inv.vbs \\myserver\myfolder\mybat.bat 2
```

Where 2 is the parameter. The shortcut will run the batch without showing the window but doesn't pass any arguments to the batch. If anyone has any ideas that would be great.

Comment: It seems like you need to first pass the param to the vbs file *then* to the batch file from the vbs file.

Answer (score 1):

(As [posted](https://superuser.com/revisions/550785/4) by [user198056](https://superuser.com/users/198056/user198056))

I found the answer. The VBS needs to include the batch file.

```
dim shell
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
shell.run "cmd /c \\myserver\myfolder\mybatch.bat 2", 0
set shell=nothing
```

When this VBS is called it passes the parameter to the batch and the batch window is hidden. I'm sorry I don't have the particulars on the syntax.